# hbase design concat long key-value pairs vs many columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

Please help me understand the best way storing information in HBase.
Basically, I have a rowkey like hashed_uid+date+session_id with metrics like duration, date, time, location, depth and so on.
I have read a lot of materials where I am bit confused. People have suggested less column family for better performance, so I am facing three options to choose:

1. Have each metrics sits in one row like `rowkey_key cf1->alias1:value`
2. Have many columns like `rowkey cf1->key1:val1, cf1->key2:val2 ...`
3. Have all the key-value pairs coded into one big string like `rowkey cf1->"k1:v1,k2:v2,k3:v3..."`

Thank you in advance. I don't know which to choose. The goal of my HBase design is to prepare for incremental windowing functions of a user profiling output, like percentiles, engagement and stat summary for last 60 days. Most likely, I will use hive for that.

Comment: I'd first ask why you want to use hbase.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, my current process is in HDFS and the volume is too big to be handled more that way. Secondly, I only found that HBASE is available for better incremental calculation and snapshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly you are confused by the similarity of naming of column family and column. These concepts are different things in HBase. Column family consist of several columns. This design is to improve the speed of access to data when you need to read only some type of columns. E.g., you have raw data and processed data. Reading processed data will not involve raw data if they are stored in separated column families. You can partially to have any numbers of columns per row key; it should be stored in one region, no more than 10GB. The design depends on what you what:

- The first variant has no alternatives when you need to store a lot of
  data per one-row key, that can't be stored in on a region. More than 
  10GB.
- Second is good when you need to get only a few metrics per
  single read per row key.
- The last variant is suitable when you
  always get all metrics per single read per row key.